# How to write() to a file byte by byte or in chunks in C

Tags: c, file-io, output, byte

I'm trying to write byte by byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes etc in chunks to a file. I currently have this code however am stuck.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<errno.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char buf[1];

    //creating output file
    int outfile = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0666);

    int infile = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);

    fread = read(infile, buf, 1);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    write(outfile);
    close(infile);
    close(outfile)

}
```

Comment: You need a loop.

Comment: It is very unefficient to process single bytes using `read`/`write`. It is better to use buffered IO. `read`/`write` are also very low level. You need a lot of code to handle incomplete IO.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", buf);` not good when reading a single byte. Maybe you want `printf("%c\n", buf[0]);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all here I can't see where you had declared `fread` variable,

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<errno.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char buf[1];

    //creating output file
    int outfile = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0666);

    int infile = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);

    fread = read(infile, buf, 1); // here fread var !!?
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    write(outfile);
    close(infile);
    close(outfile)

}
```

and this is not the way to write in a file, if you succeeded in compilation so according to this you will be able to write only one byte. You have to implement a loop either `for` loop or `while` loop in order to write all the byte from one file to another, if I am getting you correctly.

I am assuming here that you are trying to write data byte by byte from one file to another, So with that assumption here is the working code with some changes in your program..

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<errno.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int fread =0;
    char buf[1]; 

    //creating output file
    int outfile = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0666);

    int infile = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    
    while(fread = read(infile, buf, 1)){ //change here number of bytes you want to read at a time and don't forget to change the buffer size too :)
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    write(outfile, buf, fread);
   }
    close(infile);
    close(outfile)

}
```

Comment: `while(fread = read(infile, buf, 1))` not good as `read` returns -1 on error

Comment: `printf("%s\n", buf);` not good as `read` don't return strings

Comment: yeah, but actually this guy seems new in file handling so I am not editing much code and trying keep it easy for him whatever he is trying to do with the same...on your point here I am assuming it will give error when there will be nothing to read in infile and will come out from while loop.

Comment: thanks that works, I am new to file handling. Just making sure if I want to write 2 bytes at a time id change char buff[1] to char buff[2] and the number in the read function to 2?

Comment: yes, exactly.. buffer must be sufficient to hold data. You can also allocate big buffer like buff[10]  and read number of 2,3,4,5 bytes according to you.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code you read 1 byte and then print it using `%s`. That won't work. `%s` is for printing strings and strings must be zero-terminated but you won't get a zero-terminated string when using `read` (further the array `buf` can only hold an empty string). I assume you want to print the data that you read so do like:

```
printf("%c\n", buf[0]);
```

For reading the whole file, you need a loop:

```
while((fread = read(infile, buf, 1)) > 0)
{
    printf("%c\n", buf[0]);
}
```

Regarding block size you can only set a maximum but `read` may return fewer byte. So do like:

```
#define MAX_BYTES_IN_A_SINGLE_READ 4
```

to set the max block size and use it like:

```
char buf[MAX_BYTES_IN_A_SINGLE_READ];
ssize_t fread;
while((fread = read(infile, buf, MAX_BYTES_IN_A_SINGLE_READ)) > 0)
{
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < fread; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c\n", buf[i]);
    }
}
```